# R: simple multiplication causes integer overflow

Tags: r, integer-overflow

In a longer script I have to multiply the length of a vector A (2614) with the numbers of rows of a dataframe B (1456000). If I do that directly with `length(A) * nrow(B)` I get the message `NAs produced by integer overflow` although there's no problem when I multiply the same numbers:

```
2614 * 1456000 
[1] 3805984000
```

The only way to get the multiplication to work is `round(length(A)) * nrow(B)` or `length(A) * round(nrow(B))`. But the numbers produced by `length` and `nrow` must be integers anyhow! Moreover, I tested this with the following function suggested on the help page for the function is.integer...

```
is.wholenumber <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) abs(x-round(x)) < tol
```

... and of course, they ARE integers. So why do I need the crutches "round" here? Very puzzling... Somebody has got an idea what's going on in the background?

Comment: `2614 * 1456000` are **not** integer... `> class(1456000)
[1] "numeric"
> class(1456000L)
[1] "integer"`

Comment: @Michele thanks, I updated my answer a bit because of this comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hopefully a graphic representation of what is happening....

```
2614 * 1456000
#[1] 3805984000

##  Integers are actually represented as doubles
class( 2614 * 1456000 )
#[1] "numeric"

#  Force numbers to be integers
2614L * 1456000L
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#In 2614L * 1456000L : NAs produced by integer overflow

##  And the result is an integer with overflow warning
class( 2614L * 1456000L )
#[1] "integer"
#Warning message:
#In 2614L * 1456000L : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

`2614 * 1456000` is a `numeric` because both the operands are actually of class `numeric`. The overflow occurs because both `nrow` and `length` return `integer`'s and hence the result is an integer but the result exceeds the maximum size representable by the `integer` class (+/-2*10^9). A `numeric` or `double` can hold `2e-308 to 2e+308`. So to solve your problem, just use `as.numeric(length(A))` or `as.double(length(A))`.